# Computer vision Algorithm suggestions for improving Laser dots pattern more distinctive

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

I am currently looking for some computer vision algorithms to improve laser-pattern (small dots) projected on the wall to be more distinctive.

Below is my laser-pattern projected on the wall (let's call it as A) :

[image]

Below is a reference laser-pattern projected(Kinect) on the wall (Lets call it as B) :

[image]

We can clearly see that in the image A, the dots are not clearly visible and they are very close to each other. On the other hand in image B, we can see that the dots are sharp and clear. The important problem is I am not able to change the hardware (that is the laser or more powerful cameras). This is what I get out of my hardware. So,

**my question is, do you know a better algorithm or any approach (set of algorithms) to improve the quality of this Laser pattern to make those dots distinctive from each other.**

Currently, I am using the openCV library to improve the algorithm.

Comment: You are not mentioning which algorithm you are using as of the moment.

Comment: There are tons of options to go with. You can apply some thresholding to the data, see if that helps. Or you can look up peak finding algorithms. If that doesn't help, you can maybe try and incorporate some prior knowledge "knowing that you need to find a spot every so many pixels", but this would require you probably to write your own algorithm.

Comment: @Piglet, I know it is gonna be very challenging with this hardware. But that is why I posted it in StackOverflow to get some expert advice on improving it software end. Only if there is no option, then I will go for new hardware.

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve. if you only want to have some random texture on surfaces so you can do stereo matching it might be ok for some applications. if you want to locate single dots and/or locate certain patterns I would go for better hardware which is not too expensive to get better results than that. you could even salvate a laser projector from a broken kinect basically for free (if the projector wasn't the issue)

Comment: @Piglet Yes exactly, I want to have some random texture on surfaces so that I can do stereo matching.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, the pattern in image A is not intended to be used as separate dots. Instead, you'd treat it as a texture. It looks sufficiently good to determine orientation (use a 2D FFT) and measure shifts in the pattern (Calculate 2D correlation, look for a peak).

Comment: Could you brief a little more on your idea? I understood partially what you are trying to say but I still need your explanation. Thanks

Comment: @Thiya: To clarify: what I suggest will NOT improve the quality of individual dots. I challenge your statement that the quality is bad; it appears to be sufficient. The goal of this sort of illumination is to create a non-uniform texture where the surface itself is of a uniform color.